# How many parameters can I pass by reference in C++, without getting abnormal behavior

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, undefined-behavior

I had a problem with a function:

```
int parsearRestricciones(char linea[], unsigned int& x, unsigned int& y, unsigned int& tiempo, char restric[])
```

Inside that function I parse linea[].

The input consists in: three unsigned integers, and a string of punctuation characters. I need to read them that way.
The problem ocurrs when I assign *atoi(linea+offset)* to variable tiempo. Outside the function (i.e., in main() ), the value of *tiempo* is not the same that it's inside.
I had the problem only with *tiempo* (I replaced x,y and tiempo by a pointer to struct. It works)

What could be the problem?

Thanks for your help.

-----edit-again

The full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cassert>

#define MAX_RESTRIC 3  // Tres sentidos. Si hay 4, se usa '+'
#define MAX_LINEA 80
#define entrada cin


using namespace std;

int parsearRestricciones(char *linea, unsigned int& x, unsigned int& y, unsigned int& t, char *restric) {
// ! solo funciona si x,y,t,restric estan en una misma linea (i.e. no hay CR LF)

int i=0, j=0;

//Parsea x de la casilla
x = atol(linea+i);//strtol(linea,(char**)NULL,10);

while (isdigit(linea[i])) i++;
while (isspace(linea[i])) i++;

//Parsea y de la casilla
y = atol(linea+i);

while (isdigit(linea[i])) i++;
while (isspace(linea[i])) i++;
if(linea[i] == '\0')
    return -1;

//Parsea tiempo
t = atol(linea+i);
cout << "---" << t << endl;

while (!ispunct(linea[i])) i++;

//Parsea restricciones
while (linea[i] != '\0' && linea[i] != ' '){
    restric[j] = linea[i];
    i++; j++;
}
restric[j]='\0';

return 1;

}


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
// Sugerencia de argumentos
// --d  (por Dijkstra)
// --axe  (por A*, distancia euclideana)
// --axm  (por A*, distancia manhattan)

// y dos màs que veremos luego :)

unsigned int X, Y;
unsigned int xi, yi;
unsigned int xf, yf;

unsigned int x,y,tiempo;

char restricciones[MAX_RESTRIC + 1];


//Buffer para parsear las lineas con restricciones
char linea[MAX_LINEA + 1];

bool finCasos = false;
bool siguienteCaso = false;


while (!finCasos)
{

    if (siguienteCaso){
        // Se leyó otro mapa antes que éste (hubo parseo, y quedo en xcasilla,ycasilla)
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        siguienteCaso = false;

    } else {
        // Sino, lee por primera vez las dimensiones del mapa
        entrada >> X >> Y;
    }

    if ( X == 0  &&  Y == 0 )
        finCasos = true;

    else {

        entrada >> xi >> yi;

        entrada >> xf >> yf;

        // Lee restricciones hasta que encuentra una linea sin ellas (sin tiempo ni direccion)
        // se asumira, que corresponde a las dimensiones del siguiente caso, y los usará en la siguiente
        // iteracion
        while(!siguienteCaso) {

            cin.get(); //lee un '\0' que quedó (?)
            cin.getline(linea, MAX_LINEA+1);

            if ( parsearRestricciones(linea,x,y,tiempo, restricciones) == -1 ) {
                siguienteCaso = true;

            } else {

                cout << "X = " << x << endl;
                cout << "Y = " << y << endl;
                cout << "tiempo = " << tiempo << endl;
                cout << "restric = " << restricciones << endl;
                int j=0;
                cout << "restric = " ;
                while(restricciones[j]!='\0'){
                    cout << restricciones[j];j++;}
                cout << endl;

                //-- agregar datos al grafo/mapa
            }

        }

        // Resolver usando algun algoritmo
        //--- resolver(MAPA)

    }

}


return 0;
}
```

CFLAGS. -Wall -pipe -g -ggdb -DONLINE_JUDGE -DNDEBUG
(The Makefile also builds another source, for uvaonlinejudge)

Input:

```
101
10
1
1
2
2
1000 10000  100000 +++++
```

Output:

```
---100000
X = 1000
Y = 10000
tiempo = 65579
restric = +++++
restric = +++++
^X^C (I did break)
```

I just tested the program in Windows (using Code::Blocks, default settings) and it worked :/

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu in Virtualbox

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the actual function call(s) you are using and the immediately relevant code supporting the call.

Comment: @Julian: Post your source code, rather than explaining it in words.

Comment: Are you seeing those "bad" values while looking with the debugger? One time I got crazy in VC6 with strange values but I was inspecting values in the debugger with compiler optimizations ON (release mode).  
Please send your code in-context with the program. If you don't modify that ref anywhere, it shouldn't differ, except if you're doing multithreaded programming and getting side effects.

Comment: Another problem may be type-conversion related: e.g: outside of main tiempo is signed int (0xFFFFFFFF= decimal -1), but inside function same value read as unsigned is decimal (2^32)-1 (widening conversion).

Comment: @Hernán: This project doesn't use threads

Comment: This won't even compile; `atol()` returns a long, but `x` is a reference to an `unsigned int`

Comment: Can you describe where are you getting different 'tiempo' values? also, i suspect you're parsing lines in form X Y T \0 ? 

also tiempo is modified in your function (it's passed as ref and you do t=atoi(...). It is expected that can show a different value in main after exiting your function call.

Comment: note that i'm assuming you intended t=tiempo because if you're not modifying it inside your function, why pass an unsigned int variable as reference?

Comment: @BlueRaja 1) sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(long) in LLP64 or 32bit / anyway is not treated as error if it's a shortening conversion. 'Dereferencing' unsigned int&  does not require any special syntax unlike dereferencing unsigned int* x which would require atol(*x)

Comment: This is the full code. I haven't any problem in win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***How many parameters can I pass by reference in C++, without getting abnormal behavior?***

As many as you want to!

Comment: Really?  I want to create a function with 8 billion pass-by-reference arguments... time to write some autogenerated code and see what happens :)

Comment: @Jeremy: Okay, maybe it should be "As many as you can fit in available memory". Of course any computer system has limits. But the language itself does not impose limits IIRC.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: Yes really! Since OP asked `in C++` answer is as many as he likes or as many as fit in memory on his/her system, there is no limitation imposed by the language.

Comment: I verified that g++ will compile and run a function that takes 40,000 pass-by-reference arguments... I tried 400,000 but my computer only has 2GB of RAM and I got tired of listening to it swap.

Comment: The standard does not impose limits on the number of parameters, but it does recommend that if a limit exists, it be at least 256.  But that is just a recommendation.

Comment: There might not be a limit imposed directly by the language, but the language does allow such limits to be imposed by the implementation. Moreover, passing "as many as you want to!" is a good way to get Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such limit. However, your function does not use tiempo in any way, it uses some variable called t instead: `t = atol(linea+i);`

Comment: +1: It's so sad to see programmers accusing other's people software as first thought when facing a problem. It's a way of thinking that leads nowhere... in general with programming but even more specifically with C++

Comment: @Frigo: I'm sorry. I asked it after I changed the code and had to remember what I've put before. It's corrected now, but the problem is the same.

Comment: I compile it using -Wall. There wasn't any warning about unused/non-declared variables.